# Why does vue.js statement with axios start later?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, vue.js, axios

First of all, I want to store data in this.result from response.data. And I am wondering why the alert statements in bottom are started first before the '.then(function(response) is started [image: 1]

Comment: I know this is an irrelevant question but which font are you using?

Comment: I don't know well
I just use default code in visual studio with Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alerts are immediately displayed because `axios.get(..)` is non-blocking or [asynchronous](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript).

That is a key concept to understand - in the case of your app, it means you can call `axios.get(..)` without interrupting (or blocking) the program from continuing (even though the `GET` request is busily working in the background).

This is why you see the alert dialog box is immediately displayed.

When `axios.get(..)` completes or fails at a later stage, the function you supply to `.then()` or `.catch()` is called.

If you want your alert to display after you get a success response from the server, update your code as follows:

```
axios.get(.., { 
   .. 
})
.then((response) => {

    this.result = response.data;
    // Move alerts into the function within your then() handler
    alert('test');
    alert(this.result[0].model_name);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick  reply!
But the point is ,actually what I want to do is I want to store the data(this.result[0].model_name) in 'this.c1_type' and I did this like
.then(function(response) {
    this.result = response.data;
    this.c1_type = this.result[0].type;
})
I was assuming it works but unfortunately It doesn't work on out of this function.
Which means 'this.result[0].type' can be stored in this.c1_type in local but out of the function, It doesn't have any variable.

Comment: I think I better understand what you want to achieve - see the updated answer which uses arrow functions `(response) => {}` - that should allow you to store the data in the context/object that is `axios.get(..)`

Comment: YOU ARE SUCH A LEGEND!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I had been struggling with this problem for a while and now I feel relaxed from your comment.
You saved my project Thank you so much
Thanks a million!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Hi there, you are welcome - glad I could help! Please feel free to PM me directly for further help